# Problems with a for loop when replacing values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

The following line of code replaces the value for april 2020 with the mean value of the same month the four previous years in a pandas dataframe.

```
df.loc[df['Time'] == '2020-04-30', 'value'] = df.loc[df['column'].isin(['2019-04-30', '2018-04-30', '2017-04-30', '2016-04-30' ]), 'value'].mean()
```

I want to do the same operation on may, june, july etc. and started to work on a for loop. I havent dont a loop before with four diffrent values and I tries the above. But it only seeam to work for the first iteration? What am I missing?

```
date = [('2020-04-30', '2019-04-30', '2018-04-30', '2017-04-30', '2016-04-30'),
       ('2020-05-30', '2019-05-30', '2018-05-30', '2017-05-30', '2016-05-30')]

for i, j, k, l, m in date:
    df1.loc[df1['Time'] == i, 'AF_ARBETSLOSA'] = df1.loc[df1['Time'].isin([j, k, l, m]), 'AF_ARBETSLOSA'].mean()
```

I also tried this, but an error was returned "Lenghts must match".

```
y2020 = [('2020-04-30', '2020-05-30', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-30')]
y2019 = [('2019-04-30', '2019-05-30', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-30')]
y2018 = [('2018-04-30', '2018-05-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-30')]
y2017 = [('2017-04-30', '2017-05-30', '2017-06-30', '2017-07-30')]
y2016 = [('2016-04-30', '2016-05-30', '2016-06-30', '2016-07-30')]


for i, j, k, l, m in zip(y2020, y2019, y2018, y2017, y2016):
    df1.loc[df1['Time'] == i, 'AF_ARBETSLOSA'] = df1.loc[df1['Time'].isin([j, k, l, m]), 'AF_ARBETSLOSA'].mean()
```

My data looks like this:

```
              n
Time    
1994-01-31  636790
1994-02-28  622556
1994-03-31  609128
1994-04-30  588751
1994-05-31  579768
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your input data ? something like `df.head(5)`

Comment: the error in the second approach is due to the additional parentheses, it must be `y2020 = ['2020-04-30', '2020-05-30', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-30']` etc.